# Outlook rules for routing all emails sent by people not in a whitelist

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter, rules

I have the need to have all emails that do not come from my company's domain route into a certain folder in Outlook. The purpose is to give me a higher state of alert that an email was not sent through our mail system from an internal address. FYI, we have a few domains, so I would want to whitelist those. I know I can create rules for emails from a specific person, but I can't exactly add the entire internet to the junk mail/block sender list.

Is it possible to create a rule in Outlook to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider the rule below:
 1. Create a rule to move all incoming messages to a particular folder.
 2. Add an exception to exclude messages sent from your GAL:
[image]

when creating a rule to move all messages to a particular

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't go far enough into the wizard to realize I could except things. I was only looking at the first page.